# Helix swarm not loading

Tags: perforce

Working on a Debian 11 instance.

I'm trying to configure a perforce server by installing helix swarm on it. I followed the configuration, created the accounts and everything, tested the connection with the configuration file and it seemed to worked.

At the begining we had config file problems and it did indicate that.

When we fixed the issue, we had a new issue that I still have: when trying to access the server it just goes on and on and never loads.

The issue I have is that I have no logs, not on swarm and not on apache, no access, nothing.

I have no idea why it doesn't work.

Did someone encounter this issue before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So for any out there that may stumble on this error I have 2 things to say:

- The "errors" was due to the fact that helix swarm doesn't seem to be able to have a port with `ssl:` in it's config.php and that's not written anywhere and the errors when you are not using it just says to add the ssl.
- You have to install the `helix-broker` package on your server to open a non ssl connexion from the broker and connect the broker to the server.

The configuration of the broker is pretty straightforward so I won't put the config here.

EDIT:

With the help of perforce we found out that it's simply the php lib of perforce that is not installed correctly. In the swarm folder you should have a bin folder where you can find php lib file with ssl in the name. You have to manually move those file to apache2 for swarm to be able to connect in ssl without using the broker.

Comment: If I ever meet you in real life I will give you all of my material possessions

Comment: I tried to forget I ever posted something about that... Since then we discovered another way with the help of perforce support. I will update the answer.